# Positioning Axis Label to End of Axes in 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3d

How do I position the axis label so that it looks like the following picture (at the end of the axis as if it was an extension of the axis):

[image]

```
\pgfplotsset{
    every non boxed x axis/.style={
        xtick align=center,
        tick style={line width=1pt, color=black},
        x axis line style={{Latex[width=1.5mm]}-{Latex[width=1.5mm]},black,line width=1.5pt},
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west},
        xlabel=$x$
    },
     every non boxed y axis/.style={
        ytick align=center,
        tick style={line width=1pt, color=black},
        y axis line style={{Latex[width=1.5mm]}-{Latex[width=1.5mm]},black,line width=1.5pt},
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south},
        ylabel=$y$
    },
    every non boxed z axis/.style={
        ztick align=center,
        tick style={line width=1pt, color=black},
        z axis line style={{Latex[width=1.5mm]}-{Latex[width=1.5mm]},black,line width=1.5pt},
        zlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
        zlabel=$z$
    },
    tick label style={
        font=\tiny,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a complable document, you would have more chances of getting answers (starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`)

By modifying the anchors, we can position the labels. Section `17.5.1 Positioning Nodes Using Anchors` in `pgfmanual`'s documentation.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    every non boxed x axis/.style={
        xtick align=center,
        tick style={line width=1pt, color=black},
        x axis line style={{Latex[width=1.5mm]}-{Latex[width=1.5mm]},black,line width=1.5pt},
        % xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west},
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=north},
        xlabel=$x$
    },
    every non boxed y axis/.style={
        ytick align=center,
        tick style={line width=1pt, color=black},
        y axis line style={{Latex[width=1.5mm]}-{Latex[width=1.5mm]},black,line width=1.5pt},
        % ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south},
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west},
        ylabel=$y$
    },
    every non boxed z axis/.style={
        ztick align=center,
        tick style={line width=1pt, color=black},
        z axis line style={{Latex[width=1.5mm]}-{Latex[width=1.5mm]},black,line width=1.5pt},
        % zlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
        zlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
        zlabel=$z$
    },
    tick label style={
        font=\tiny,
    }
}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,view/h=100]
        \addplot3 coordinates {
            (1,1,1) 
            };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]